# R: scatterplot from list

Tags: r, list, plot, scatter

I have data similar to the following:

```
a <- list("1999"=c(1:50), "2000"=rep(35, 20), "2001"=c(100, 101, 103))
```

I want to make a scatterplot where the x axis is the years (1999, 2000, 2001 as given by the list names) and the y axis is the value within each list. Is there an easy way to do this? I can achieve something close to what I want with a simple `boxplot(a)`, but I'd like it to be a scatterplot rather than a boxplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a data frame with the year in one column and the value in the other, and then you could plot that the appropriate columns:

```
b <- data.frame(year=as.numeric(rep(names(a), sapply(a, length))), val=unlist(a))
plot(b)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want

```
do.call(rbind,
  lapply(names(a), function(year) data.frame(year = year, obs = a[[year]]))
)
```

Or break it up into two function calls (`lapply` and then `do.call`) to make it more understandable what's going on.  It's pretty simple if you go through it. The `lapply` creates one dataframe per year where each year gets all the values for that year in the list. Now you have 3 dataframes. Then `do.call` binds these dataframes together.

Answer (score 0):

An option using `tidyr/dplyr/ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
unnest(a, year) %>%
             ggplot(., aes(x=year, y=x)) +
                    geom_point(shape=1)
```